# Body elements disappearing as I run webpack with html-webpack-plugin dependency

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I have tried looking for this problem on the internet and couldn't find anything related. I am trying to build a small project where the body of my HTML will only have one div with `id="content"` and I have to append the rest of the elements one-by-one to this div. Now I created an element `h1` and appended it to the aforementioned div and then hit the npm run build command in the terminal. As soon as webpack emits a bundle, the div `id="content"` disappears from the body. I am attaching the screenshot of the issue. This is how the index.html look like before I run webpack:
[image: Index.html file]
index.js stays the same after running webpack:
[image: index.js file]
This is how index.html looks like after I run the command `npm run build` or `npm run watch`:
[image: index.html after running webpack]
Here is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports ={
    entry: {
        index:{
            import: './src/index.js'
        }
    },
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins : [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Resturant Page',
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.png|jpg|jpeg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff|wof$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting your index.html as a template in HtmlWebpackPlugin? Like this example: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/main/docs/template-option.md#1-dont-set-any-loader

Comment: It did solve the issue, but now I am getting another problem. As soon as I run the `build` command `<script defer src="index.bundle.js"></script>` this tag is getting duplicated in the head, which means the heading is getting appended twice in the `content` div.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out what mistake I was making. I had manually added the script tag before and when the webpack would run it would add the script tag also, hence the duplication. Thank you for the help @IrfanullahJan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the HtmlWebpackPlugin lines with following:

```
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      inject: false, // prevents adding script tag to html so you may do it manually
    })
  ]
```

I suggest keeping index.html in `src` folder, Webpack will copy the output to `dist` for you.

Also, instead of `inject: false` it is much better to let it be added automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now what you mean. The tutorial I was following had kept files in this way. So, this plugin is doing all the effort for us that we would have to do manually otherwise. Nice.